# NSTableRowView weird behaviour on drag and drop (keeps inserting NSView in the view hierarchy)

Tags: swift, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview, nstablerowview

I've noticed strange behaviour in my app and cannot find a way to fix it:
I have **NSOutlineView** with a custom **NSTableRowView** and support of drag and drop.

When I drag item(file for example) on outlineview first it draws correct hightlight (I've override **drawDraggingDestinationFeedbackInRect**), but on second drag I have this blue highlight and if I debug the view hierarchy I can see that **NSView** being added to the row.

I've attached small animation which shows exactly what happens (I've also added **NSTableView** with the same **NSTableRowView**):

Top    : **NSOutlineView**

Bottom : **NSTableView**

[image]

View hierarchy (for the NSOutlineView):

[image]

Here is my code for **NSTableRowView**

```
import Cocoa

class TestRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override func drawSelectionInRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.yellowColor().setFill()
        NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).fill()
    }

    override func drawDraggingDestinationFeedbackInRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.greenColor().setFill()
        NSBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).fill()
    }

}
```

Here are datasource and delegate methods for **NSOutlineView** :

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
    return item == nil ? allItems.count : 0
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
    return allItems[index]
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {
    return outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("DataCell", owner: self)
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, rowViewForItem item: AnyObject) -> NSTableRowView? {
    return TestRowView()
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, heightOfRowByItem item: AnyObject) -> CGFloat {
    return 60.0
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    return item
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, item: AnyObject?, childIndex index: Int) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, validateDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, proposedItem item: AnyObject?, proposedChildIndex index: Int) -> NSDragOperation {
    return .Copy
}
```

What I've tried :

1. Subclassing NSOutlineView and overriding acceptsFirstResponder
2. Overriding backgroundStyle
3. Tried different selectionHighlightStyle's
4. Used  NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleNone

Comment: Overriding the `draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle` property of `TestRowView` and always returning `.None` might work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a sort of solution to my problem, here is what I've done :

First thing - subclass **NSOutlineView** with the following property being overriden :

```
override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool{
    get{
        return false
    }
}
```

Secondly in my **NSTableRowView** subclass, I've added following :

```
override var selectionHighlightStyle: NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle {
    get{
        return self.emphasized ? .None:.Regular
    }
    set{

    }
}
```

I cannot say that this a good solution or even a complete solution, but better than nothing.

Sometimes I'm still getting the grey background, so I've also added a check inside setter of  the `override var backgroundStyle : NSBackgroundStyle` property inside my **NSTableCellView** subclass.